# Update date field with null value using JS remoting?

Tags: javascript-remoting, field-update, date

With the Rest Toolkit, creating or updating an optional date field with an empty string results in an **Invalid date** error. Using `null` instead results in another error: **Argument 1 cannot be null**.

How can you make the field null?

```
client.update('Transaction__c', 'a0Ni0000000H1kWCHA', {Name: "1078", Date__c: "2013-03-14", Due_Date__c: ""}, function(){})
```

Comment: Can you not just use the value `null`?

Comment: Could you please share some of your code?

Comment: @LaceySnr: I've tried `null` to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, that looks like my bug.  You'll see that other types convert an empty string to null: http://bit.ly/10W3MIE  If you fix it before I get a chance, please open a pull request.

Comment: Fixed and working. Thanks for the tip: http://bit.ly/170bhFK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the empty string to null in **RemoteTKController.cls** by changing

`obj.put(key, Date.valueOf(svalue));`

to

`obj.put(key, svalue == '' ? null : Date.valueOf(svalue));`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this could be a limitation of the toolkit. If the remoting is being done in a VF page you could instead call a method your own apex method which could look for a specific date such as 01-01-1900 and set it to `null` when needed.

If you're outside of the platform (sounds like you might be) and really need this functionality then you could use a similar approach, set a specific date that wouldn't be used otherwise (01/01/1900) and then use a trigger to set that field to `null`.